# PHP form not posting to Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I am pretty new to PHP and SQL scripting so this is probably an easy fix that I just can't figure out.  I have a database called InventoryControl with an assets table under it.  For testing purposes so I can figure my way around PHP and SQL, I had a very simple webpage with a single form:

```
<form action="insertasset.php" method="post">
Asset Tag: <input type="text" name="assettag" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

On submit, it will load this php script:

```
<?php
echo "PHP TEST!";
echo $_POST["assettag"];
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","sampleuser","samplepass");
if (!$con)
  {
  echo "CONNECTION FAILED!";
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "I succeeded!";
mysql_select_db("InventoryControl", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO assets (asset_tag, manufacturer, model, type, location, decomissioned, employee_owner, computer_name, price, day, month, yea$
VALUES
('$_POST[assettag]', asdf, asdf, asdf, 0, 0, asdf, asdf, 0, 0, 0, 0)";
echo "Posted!";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  echo "I didn't work";
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);


?>
```

I have added multiple lines of echo's in there for testing to see where the failure occurs but I am stuck with the issue of the only responses I get from running the PHP script is 
"PHP TEST!" and then the information that I just posted from the previous form.  So, I know it is loading the PHP script, and that it is posting the data from the form, but I can't seem to get it into the table.  The table doesn't have any requirements for columns to be filled as far as I know (I set it up with pretty basic parameters, the asset_tag is the primary key, otherwise its just columns to hold data).  If anyone could give a newbie some help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` extension and [choose a more appropriate MySQL API](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: your strings `asdf` must be quoted as `'asdf'` inside the VALUES list

Comment: By the way, I know the line for $sql=... has odd syntax, its because I tried copying and pasting from Putty and I didn't get all of the text

Comment: Also, your script is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You have not protected `$_POST['assettag']`

Comment: @Michael I previously didn't have the 'asdf' input, but it still didn't work.  Also, I am unsure of how to protect $_POST against injection, could you supply me with a decent source I could study please?

Comment: @StephenR: http://bobby-tables.com  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: do you get any error, if you have error reporting turned off, then enable it by placing this on top of the page `error_reporting(1);`

Comment: @MarcB Thank you, I will research that.

Comment: to understand SQL injection, think about what your query will look like if someone enters "'); DROP TABLE assets;--" in your text input. an easy way to fix this is to use mysql_real_escape_string. Or better yet, look into this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar I am not sure I understand, but I removed the calls for "mysql_error()" and placed "error_reporting(1)" at the top.  I get the same results

Comment: @AdrianMester I had a basic idea of SQL injections, I was just unsure of what techniques were used to prevent it from happening.  I will definitely have to look into preventing it from happening, but in the meantime I plan on creating a second layer of protection by authenticating to the database before having access to the form to add least ensure "authorized" access

Comment: @SteveRobillard Yes, I tried copying and pasting from Putty and failed to make the screen wide enough so it showed the dollar sign to show there was more text there.

Comment: $_POST[assettag] in query should be $_POST["assettag"]m also in values ... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html READ!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you use mysql_query() function use it like this:

```
mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());
```

That way you will see the error.

When it comes to your problem, you need to single quote your values in INSERT INTO statement.

BUT ALSO you can single quote column names. Sometimes column names can be special keywords like "order".

You can see the error details more clearly if you use it with mysql_error().

Comment: I wish I could see what the mysql_error() function was returning, but sadly I get no response beyond echo "PHP TEST!" and echo "$_POST["assettag"]

Comment: put the same thing mysql_select_db and mysql_connect too. Maybe you have an error in those lines.

Comment: Have you looked in the server's error logs to see if there's anything going in there?

Comment: can you connect to the mysql client using the sampleuser and samplepassword? I.e, from the command line, can you use mysql -u sampleuser -p (and then type the password at the prompt)?  Just to check your auth credentials are correct

Comment: I haven't checked the logs, I didn't know any debugging would be sent there, and yes I can connect to the database with my credentials from Mysql Workbench as well as from the command line

Comment: Did you put the mysql_error() line near mysql_select_db and mysql_connect as I suggested? What's the result, any errors?

Comment: "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/test.php on line 5.  Which is the line $con = mysql....

Comment: You probably don't have mysql exteions. Google for php mysql extension. Installation depends on if you are on windows or mac or linux but there are many great tutorials. Then try my solution.

Comment: @AtaS. I made considerable progress when I realized I must have not had the mysql extensions installed - I thought I had them included in a standard package install of php5.  I can now post information in my table from the PHP script - but for some reason I keep getting an error suggesting that I am inserting duplicate primary keys and then updating the table anyways....  May I ask what your opinion is of using mysql_* commands as opposed to using the mysqli extension?

Comment: Well mysql_* commands can't be related to any "duplicated entry". That error is specific to MySQL-side. There's probably alread a record and you want to insert a new record with the same ID of old one. When we come to the mysql_* commands, I'm really old in PHP, I don't use it now. So of course new libraries are better, faster, more optimized and secure and should be used. I don't deal with projects in PHP so I'm happy with my knowledge of mysql_* functions. But you should of course try to learn new ones, seems like you are actively using it! mysql_* functions are the old ones.

Comment: The problem is the data I am sending to the column marked as the primary key is completely unique (for now I am simply sending it random key mashing strings).  I always get a warning saying that a duplicate exists, but then it adds the data anyways.  Its a strange predicament.  I have been having some fun branching out in my overall technical and programming skills, but I seem to hit a lot of brick walls on my way to learning the basics - so I appreciate your help!  I will definitely see if I can learn newer extensions and see if their functionality makes me happy.

Comment: We really should know the table structure, and keys of the table to help more on that error. Also the exact error itself and sample data you insert.

Comment: The only key I have, the primary key, is asset_tag which is the data I am posting from the html form.  I get the strange feeling it is attempting to Insert the same data twice somehow.
Update:...just found the issue.  I was indeed trying to pass the data to the table twice on accident.

Comment: What is the data structure of asset_tag? varchar(255)? Can you provide a sample data it currently has on a few records?

Answer (score 0):

```
$asset=$_POST['assettag'];
$sql="INSERT INTO assets VALUES ('".$asset."', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf', 0, 0, 'asdf', 'asdf', 0, 0, 0, 0)";
echo "Posted!";
if (!mysql_query($sql))
{
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 echo "I didn't work";
}
```